# Is it possible to implement / run Java Real Time program in Windows?

Tags: java, real-time, real-time-java, rtsj

I am very new to Java and also Real Time Program. I am trying to run some real time code using Eclipse or Netbeans in Windows, however, I face same problem for both IDE which I could not import the javax.realtime package.

I had googled for several hours just to get this package, but I came across quite a lot resources pointing to Java real time virtual machine. Is it not possible to have the real time features in Windows? If yes, can I get some help here for me to run those real time program in Ubuntu running from a VM?

Any feedback is highly appreciated...

Thank you very much...

Comment: It looks like there's a couple of implementations available here: http://www.rtsj.org/docs/more.html

Comment: last I looked at RTSJ, which was 2009, there wasn't any *true* realtime for windows, on the basis that windows doesn't have the necessaries to support it. However, you can easily create stubs for it that will let you build on windows, which may make your development easier.

Comment: Hi, can you explain more on "create stubs for it that will let you build on windows"? Need it so much... thanks!!

Comment: well .. it's a piece of work, but you basically just make fake versions of the realtime classes that you need. lets you compile your business logic, but might not even run, on windows. You can take it to the next level by actually putting some approximate behavior into your stub classes, and maybe even run on windows that way, but the timing behavior will not reliable. Anyway, I'm basing this on experience from 2008/2009. Would certainly investigate the web for RTSJ packages for windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer looks like no.

Over at [Java RTS](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/realtime/index.jsp#requirements) is says the requirements are:

> Real-Time OS:
>
> - Solaris 10 (Update 6, Update 7)
> - SUSE Linux Enterprise Real Time 10 Service Pack 2 (SP2) update 6 (2.6.22.19-0.22-rt kernel)
> - Red Hat Enterprise MRG 1.1

--note--
I was going to edit/comment on someone else's post but it looks like it has disappeared :(